# Trying to use CSS class Together with Nth- child selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Hi I have looked at a variety of resources including Stackoverflow on how to use an Nth child selector and Class together and so far I am still failing.

Essentially my menu has Main categories (class =cat) and sub categories (class=subcat)

I want Each of the Main categories to be coloured differently. sub categories all stay the same. it is likely there may be multiple subcats in between each main cat. So, example:

**Beef**
     steak
     roast
**Chicken**
     Breast
     drumsticks
     wings
**Fish**
     Salmon

I can make it work so long as I don't put the class in - the instant the class goes in the nth-child selector fails.

css:

```
    #nav ul li.cat a {
display:block;
background-color: #265054;
font-size: 1em;
padding-left: 25px;
height: 18px;
padding-top: 2px;
margin: 1px 0px;
color: #FFFF00;

}

#nav ul li.cat a:nth-child(2)  {
background-color: #728c8c;
}
```

Code:

```
<?php 
    if (count($navlist)){ 
        echo "<ul>"; 
        foreach ($navlist as $key => $list){ 
            foreach ($list as $topkey => $toplist){ 
                echo "<li class='cat'>"; 
                echo anchor("welcome/cat/$topkey",$toplist['name']); 
                echo "</li>\n"; 

                if (count($toplist['children'])){ 
                    foreach ($toplist['children'] as $subkey => $subname){ 
                        echo "\n<li id='subcat'>"; 
                        echo anchor("welcome/cat/$subkey",$subname); 
                        echo "</li>"; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        echo "</ul>\n"; 
    } 
?>
```

Many Thanks for all your help !

Comment: What browser are you using?  nth-child is only supported on IE as of version 9.

Comment: I'm developing in dreamweaver and testing in FF 11.0

Comment: Care to supply an example of how you've structured your HTML? I suspect that's the real trouble.

Comment: Good Question. If all my Main Categories were to have the same coloured background, then I would not need an Nth-child selector. However, I want each Main category to have a different colour depending on their position in the sequence rather than their content .. so the first might be blue, the second red and so forth

Comment: Here is my HTML - it is wrapped up in  in Codeigniter / PHP: Sorry Guys - I have no lcue how to use this strange way of entering code into the site so it comes out formatted.

Comment: `code` <?php

if (count($navlist)){

  echo "<ul>";
  foreach ($navlist as $key => $list){
   foreach ($list as $topkey => $toplist){
     echo "<li class='cat'>";
     echo anchor("welcome/cat/$topkey",$toplist['name']);
     echo "</li>\n";
     if (count($toplist['children'])){
      foreach ($toplist['children'] as $subkey => $subname){
       echo "\n<li id='subcat'>";
       echo anchor("welcome/cat/$subkey",$subname); 
       echo "</li>";
      }
     }
 }
  }
  echo "</ul>\n";
}


?>`code`

Comment: Could you give us the HTML that is outputted by that script?

Comment: sure - but I am struggling to get the code formatted for this site:

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong - but i can't get the site to take my code in the Add Comment box

Comment: @Vince Use the main question area. I updated it for you.

Comment: do you mean the "answer your question" button .. do I want to answer my own question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is wrong, here it is corrected, and since you only want to style the main categories styled, I've added a  `>` child selector.

```
#nav ul li.cat:nth-child(2) > a  {
  background-color: #728c8c;
}
```

**Demo: [jsfiddle.net/kjxtg](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/kjxtg/)**

Comment: thanks marcel but unfortunately that didn't work. I just ignored the nth child selector

Comment: @VinceJacobs: Seems to work fine in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/kjxtg/).

Comment: Heah Marcel - you are a super star ! I need to figure out what is going on .. perhaps my html isn't right. Many thanks !

Comment: There musty be something odd in my HTML because I can not get your solution to work in my HTML .. I'd like to post my HTML but for the life of me I can not see how to do that in this site - I'm used to PHP freaks where it seems more obvious,

Comment: @VinceJacobs: Edit your original question at the top, paste in the `HTML`, highlight it and click the button that looks like `{}`, it's 5th from the left.

Answer (score 0):

If your goal was simply to have the children of each category have a different color, try this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2yqaz/. If you look at the HTML markup, you'll see the "common" way of marking this up:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="cat">
            <a href="">Beef</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Steak</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Raost</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="cat">
            <a href="">Chicken</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Breast</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Drumstick</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Wing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="cat">
            <a href="">Fish</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">Salmon</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

HTH.

Comment: Thanks Tiesen, what I really need is a way  of giving each Main category a different colour, hence the need for nth-child selectors. what You kindly gave me was a solution for getting all the Main Cats the same colour.

Answer (score 0):

So on my own observation "nth-child" will work if the element is direct child. Please refer to here
http://jsfiddle.net/fuPJs/

If you notice in the code, these lines:

```
<li class="cat">
        <a href="">Beef</a>
        <a href="">Steak</a>
        <a href="">Raost</a></li>
    </li>
```

they are a direct child of class="cat" so your css selector works for "nth-child". The rest of them are not direct child that's why it did not work.

Hope that helps.

Best,

Comment: Thanks so much shen but sadly your efforts did not work. Your css does not isolate the Main Categories by the class. Your N-child selector does give different colours but simply to the next li which could be a sub category.